# Ball going through paddle when increasing velocity

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Pong game and so far I have everything working for me other than the ball. At first I had the ball's x and y axis move up by one space each time. It was working fine until i decided to increase it to 2. I cant figure out what is wrong with my code and I need help.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Pong extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

int x = 90;
int y = 90;
int rectytop = 30;
int rectytop2 = 30;
int rectybottom = rectytop + 100; 
int rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;

int border = 30;
boolean balldown = true;
boolean ballright = true;
boolean playerborderup = false;
boolean playerborderdown = false;
boolean balltouch1 = false;
boolean balltouch2 = false;


private void moveball() {

    if (balldown == true){
        y = y + 2;
    }

    if (y == getHeight()-border){
        balldown = false;
    }
   if (balldown == false){
        y = y - 2;
    }






   if (ballright == true){
       x = x + 2;
   }
   if (x == getWidth()-border){
       ballright = false;
   }
   if (ballright == false){
       x = x - 2;
   }



   if (y == 0){
       balldown = true;
   }

   if (x == 0){
       ballright = true;
   }



   if (balltouch1 == false){
       if (x == 75){
           if(y < rectybottom && y > rectytop){
               ballright = true;
           }
       }
   }


   if (balltouch2 == false){
       if (x == 390 && y < rectybottom2 && y > rectytop2){
               ballright = false;
       }
   }


}    

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    //drawing ball and paddles 
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    g.fillRect(45 , rectytop, 30, 100);
    g.fillRect(425, rectytop2, 30, 100);

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //making the window
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Pong Game");
    Pong game = new Pong();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500, 500);//1024, 724
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.addKeyListener(game);

    //game code

    f.add(game);        
    while (true){
        game.repaint();
        game.moveball();

        Thread.sleep(10);


    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    //player one
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        if (rectytop == 0){
            playerborderup = true;
        }
        if (rectytop != 0){
            playerborderup = false;
        }
        if (playerborderup == true){
            rectytop = rectytop + 0;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderup == false){
            rectytop = rectytop - 5;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        if (rectytop == 585){
            playerborderdown = true;
        }
        if (rectytop != 585){
            playerborderdown = false;
        }
        if (playerborderdown == true){
            rectytop = rectytop - 0;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderdown == false){
            rectytop = rectytop + 5;
            rectybottom = rectytop + 100;
            repaint();
        }
    }


    //player two
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        if (rectytop2 == 0){
            playerborderup = true;
        }
        if (rectytop2 != 0){
            playerborderup = false;
        }
        if (playerborderup == true){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 + 0;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderup == false){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 - 5;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        if (rectytop2 == 585){
            playerborderdown = true;
        }
        if (rectytop2 != 585){
            playerborderdown = false;
        }
        if (playerborderdown == true){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 - 0;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
        if (playerborderdown == false){
            rectytop2 = rectytop2 + 5;
            rectybottom2 = rectytop2 + 100;
            repaint();
        }
    }







}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }





}
```

Comment: What is your question specifically?  Maybe there is a bug in which the `balltouch` code is not working?

Comment: I don't have time to read over all the code, but when something like this happened to me, it was because the increased velocity caused the ball to move so much per tick that the ball never actually touched the paddle, so it never interacts. Make sure that the balk is actually interacting with the paddle.

Comment: So if I add a swing timer, would the problem be fixed?  If so can anyone show me how?

Comment: A timer is overkill. Instead you can lower the speed when it comes close to a border or follow one of the answers below.

Comment: Ok so the other people answered and my program seemed to be fixed. But now that I got the ball to move accordingly, the paddle lags. What should I do about that?

Comment: Lag is a very diverse problem. When are you lagging and under what conditions? Do you have a screencast? Is it only when the ball is near the paddle?

Comment: The lag occurs when you start to hold down the up or down button. But after a little it starts growing smoothly.

Comment: Put output statements inside every if statement for the keypress part. If something ouputs a lot when you start to hold down the up/down button, thats where your logic is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `if (x == 75)` to detect collision with the left paddle.  But if speed is 2 than the ball's `x` is always even and never equals 75.  For a quick fix, check x against a range:  `if (x > 60 && x < 75)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are moving by 2 every time, it may "skip" over some coordinates. Thus when you say

```
if (y == getHeight()-border){
    balldown = false;
}
```

y might go from getHeight()-border + 1 to getHeight()-border - 1 and never meet this condition. Thus, change it to a  range or a less than. Your new code should be

```
if (y <= getHeight()-border +1){
    balldown = false;     //change the +1 and -1 to have difference at least speed number
}
```

Note that you must do the same for the other ifs with ==, change

```
if (x == getWidth()-border){
    ballright = false;
}

if (y == 0){
    balldown = true;
}

if (x == 0){
    ballright = true;
}
```

to

```
if (x <= getWidth()-border +1){
    ballright = false;
}

if (y <= 1){
    balldown = true;
}

if (x <= 1){
    ballright = true;
}
```

Note that you can resolve the problem also by saying if the position is eer exactly one away from the border, temporarily decrement position by 1 instead of 2.